# Health benefits & enzymes different between Thermophilic and Mesophilic Probiotic cultures?

Tags: enzymes, fermentation, thermophilia

Is there a difference between the Enzymes produced by [Thermophilic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermophile) vs [Mesophilic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesophile) Probiotic cultures ? are there any other differences in [health benefits](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10721914) between the two types of cultures ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Thermophilic** and **mesophilic** enzymes **differ** in the **optimal** working **temperature,** due to a structural adaptation: thermophilic enzymes have more stiff surface-exposed loops than their mesophilic orthologs. **Human** is **mesophile,** which means that mesophilic enzymes, no matter whether human or bacterial, will work in human more efficiently.

---

Bjelic, Brandsdal, and Aqvist (2008) *Cold adaptation of enzyme reaction rates.* Biochemistry 47: 10049-10057; emphasis mine:

> **[P]sychrophilic, mesophilic, and hyperthermophilic** citrate synthases
>   ... have increasingly stronger electrostatic **stabilization of the
>   transition state,** while the energetic penalty in terms of internal
>   protein interactions follows the reverse order with the cold-adapted
>   enzyme having the most favorable energy term. The **lower activation
>   enthalpy** and **more negative activation entropy** observed for
>   **cold-adapted enzymes** are found to be associated with a **decreased
>   protein stiffness.** The origin of this effect is, however, not
>   localized to the active site but to other regions of the protein
>   structure.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18759500

---

Aqvist (2017) *Cold adaptation of triosephosphate isomerase.* Biochemistry 56: 4169-4176; emphasis mine:

> The results show that the enzyme from the psychrophilic bacterium
>   *Vibrio marinus* indeed displays the characteristic shift in
>   enthalpy-entropy balance, compared to that of the yeast ortholog. The
>   origin of this effect is found to be located in a few **surface-exposed
>   protein loops** that **show differential mobilities** in the two enzymes.
>   Key mutations render these **loops more mobile** in the **cold-adapted**
>   triosephosphate isomerase, which explains both the **reduced activation
>   enthalpy** contribution from the protein surface and the **lower
>   thermostability.**

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28731682